# Declared function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

My `switchTurns` functions is not working when I write it as a function like this:

```
function switchTurns (player){
  if (player == 'X'){
    player = 'O';
  } else {
    player = 'X';
  }
}
```

However, when I just write what is inside the declaration, it works:

```
if (player == 'X'){
  player = 'O';
} else {
  player = 'X';
}
```

This is where I use that: (It works when I use the commented part)

```
var turn = 'X';

$('.xo-btns').click(function(){
  if (against != 'PC'){
    show(this, turn, board);
    // someoneWon(board);
    switchTurns (turn);
    // if (turn == 'X'){
    //   turn = 'O';
    // } else {
    //   turn = 'X';
    // }
  }
});
```

How can I make the function work?

Comment: you need to return the changed value, and capture that in the calling function

Comment: As an aside, you can write that in one line with `player = player === 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';` (rather than a full if/else structure).

Comment: @karthikr how to you capture it?

Comment: @nnnnnn I know but I kind of want to do a function with that.

Comment: Yeah, but even within the function you could `return player === 'X' ? 'O' : 'X'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setting values to **turn** instead **player** inside the switchTurns function

Jquery

```
var turn = 'X';
var against = "Mobile";

$('.xo-btns').click(function(){
  if (against != 'PC'){
    // show(this, turn, board);
    // someoneWon(board);
    switchTurns (turn);
    console.log(turn);
  }
});

function switchTurns (player){
  if (player == 'X'){
    turn = 'O';
  } else {
    turn = 'X';
  }
}
```

Here is the working sample:https://jsfiddle.net/bu3gnpqc/

Comment: There's not really any point passing in `player` as an argument if the value being passed is just the global `turn` variable and the function updates that same global.

Answer (score 2):

You are changing a variable that's local to the function you've called, player. So when you call it in the function, it changes player but as soon as you've left the function the value is discarded. When you call it in the outer method, you're actually changing the variable turn.

Comment: Is there any way to call the variable turn?

Comment: IMO you should use a closure (and definitely check out scoping rules for javascript, they will help with a lot of things). Here's an example of how that might be done: https://jsfiddle.net/wvqcmn6v/

Comment: Thanks i'll definitely check out the scoping rules.